# Image does not appear

Tags: java, swing, oop, jlabel

Im trying to use JLabel to insert a image into my GUI. However it does not appear

Here is a partial of my code

```
public FirstAid() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 507);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel = new JPanel();


ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/method_1.png");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

    panel.add(label);
    tabbedPane.addTab("name", null, panel, null);
```

Comment: Your edit and added code changes the whole question now (and nullifies my answer). Shouldn't that code and information have been part of your **original question**? At this point, I suggest that you create and post a [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do i create a new question then?

Comment: No, my answer is obviously not *the* answer, so un-accept it, and then try to improve your current question right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a JPanel called panel, add a JLabel to it, but do nothing with the panel variable after this. You must add it to your GUI for the JLabel and the image it might hold to be seen. I'm guessing that you want to add panel to your JTabbedPane, but without more information, I can only guess.

Edit: your edited question now shows that you're adding the JPanel to the JTabbedPane. If you're still not seeing the image, then the problem is likely in your reading in of the image. Myself, I use `ImageIO.read(...)` and try to read the image in as an InputStream or as a URL.  Key to all of these methods is to make sure that you have the image path correct, and don't make any assumptions about how you might think that it is correct. The only way to know for sure is to test it.